# Express serving static files and routing

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am using express js
My root path is /xyz/

if the path is xyz/api/ i want to serve json for any other path i want to serve static file . Eg xyz/abc or xyz/def/bjk etc
My current configuration is as below

```
app.use('/xyz/:path',Express.static(path.join(__dirname,'/app')));
app.get('/xyz/api/user', authApi.user);
```

Comment: What is happening currently? :-)

Comment: All the api requests are going to static file route :) Not working :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the routes to come before serving your static content and you do not need the `:path` url param

```
app.get('/xyz/api/user', authApi.user);
app.use('/xyz/',Express.static(path.join(__dirname,'/app')));
```

Comment: xyz/abc or xyz/def/bjk these routes dont work still . Can you please help