# Express Server Cannot GET /products on Postman

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I created a server using Express, Sequelize and mySql. The below code is my route for product:

```
const express = require('express');
const Product = require('../models/product');

const router = express.Router();

router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
    /* const products = await Product.findAll();
    if (product) {
        res.status(200).send({message: 'Product found successfully', data: products})
    } else {
        res.status(404).send({message: 'Product not found'})
    } */
    res.status(200).end()
});

router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const product = await Product.create(req.body);
        res.send(product)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
   
})

module.exports = router;
```

This is my server.js code:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
require("dotenv").config();
const cors = require("cors");
const endpoints = require("express-list-endpoints");
const port = 5555;
const productRouter = require("./src/routes/product");
/* const variantRouter = require("./src/routes/variant"); */

const sequelize = require("./src/db/config");

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));

var corsOption = {
  origin: true,
  methods: "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",
  credentials: true,
  exposedHeaders: ["x-auth-token"],
};

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors(corsOption))

app.use("products", productRouter);
/* app.use("variant", variantRouter); */

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Server is Healthy!");
});

sequelize.sync({ force: true }).then(() => {
  console.log("Drop and re-sync db.");
});
console.log(endpoints(app));

app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
  console.log(`server is listening at http://localhost:${process.env.PORT}`),
    sequelize.authenticate().then(
      () => console.log("DB Connected"),
      (err) => console.log("Error in connection", err)
    );
});
```

I also have my model here:

```
const sequelize = require("../db/config");
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
const Variant = require("./variants")

const Product = sequelize.define("products", {
  id: {
    type: Sequelize.UUID,
    primaryKey: true,
  },
  product_name: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  product_description: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  date_uploaded: {
      type: Sequelize.DATE,
      allowNull: true
  },
  date_edited: {
      type: Sequelize.DATE,
      allowNull: true,
  },
  product_varieties: {
    type : Sequelize.UUID,
    reference: {
        model: 'variant',
        key: 'id'
    }
  }, 
}, 
{timestamp: false}
);


module.exports = Product;
```

The route in my server JS is working showing the String sent.
But the route from product.js is not working. Telling me can't GET and can't POST on /products

What is the solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the `/` before `products` in `app.use("/products")`

Comment: Thank you. Working now

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your static public folder has conflicted with the API router, try putting every API router before the `app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));`

I found the solution here: [Express serving static files and routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42977068/express-serving-static-files-and-routing)